# How we suffer by making others suffer?

Tags: karma, bhagavata-purana

I would like to see an example from the scriptures  of how someone has suffered as a result of  making someone else suffer.

Specially I would prefer something from Srimad Bhagavatam.

Comment: Good question.  I think, it can be answered from Bhagavata purana.